# Display Resolutions - fewer options after updating macOS to 12.3

Tags: display, resolution

I've just installed macOS 12.3, and in doing so it's removed all the resolution options for my 40" dell U4021QW monitor.

I held down <kbd>Option</kbd> and clicked "Scaled" to set a custom resolution, but now I just see the 5120 x 2160 (insanely small), and the next one is 3360 x 1418 (far too big for me), and from then on bigger and bigger scaling options. Before this update there were many many more options in-between - here's what I see now:

[image]

Is there anything I can do to get these back? I've tried installing a tool called "EasyRes" that's supposed to list all options, but it only lists the same options there too.

Comment: Have you tried ticking "Show all resolutions", shown in your screenshot?

Comment: Yeah all it does is give me low resolution versions of the same:

5120 x 2160
3360 x 1418
3360 x 1418 (low resolution)
...

Comment: Old, but you may get more resolutions with RDM: https://github.com/avibrazil/RDM

Answer (score 0):

Here's a web page on that topic.  I try to keep it current.

https://penhelm.com/data/Mac_extra_high_resolutions.html

Comment: Hello, pen-helm. This is considered a "link-only" answer. It would be helpful for future visitors to this question if you would [edit] in a summary of that page. Links can become broken or outdated so a summary would still provide the necessary information.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/321464)